# How do I integrate WebPack with VS?

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, webpack

I have been trying for days unsuccessfully to get `WebPack` to automatically build my `Vue.js` SPA application. How do I press [F5] in VS and get webpack to automatically do a build?

## Startup.cs

```
using MyApp.Domain.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyApp.Api {
  public class Startup {
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {
      services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
      services.AddSpaStaticFiles(config => {
        config.RootPath = "Client/dist";
      });

      services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository, InMemoryUserRepository>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger) {
      if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
          HotModuleReplacement = true
        });
      }
      else {
        app.UseHsts();
      }

      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
      app.UseMvc();
      app.UseSpa(spa => {});
    }
  }
}
```

## Webpack Config

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: { 'main': './Client/src/main.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Client/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'dist/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      // this will apply to both plain `.js` files
      // AND `<script>` blocks in `.vue` files
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      },
      // this will apply to both plain `.css` files
      // AND `<style>` blocks in `.vue` files
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]
  },
  plugins: [
    // make sure to include the plugin!
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ]
};
```

## main.js (vue)

```
import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './site.css';
import './index.html';

import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

import router from './router';

new Vue({
  render: v => v(App),
  router
}).$mount('#app');
```

Currently I have an extension in VS which I run manually to run the webpack. I tried an old Vue.js template (for .NET core 2) but that after lots of hacking I could not get it to work without MVC "Views", I want to only be using "Index.html" (the default file) because I am making an SPA.

Also tried `Vue-CLI`, which worked perfectly on its own, but inside VS I end up with the same problem.

Also tried https://github.com/soukoku/aspnetcore-vue which sounded promising but does not even launch the home page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about webpack, specifically, but for things like gulp and grunt, the tasks will be filled out in the Task Runner Explorer in Visual Studio. If you don't have this window already, go to View > Other Windows > Task Runner Explorer.

Inside the window, a dropdown on the left lists your various projects with build scripts. After selecting your project, the tasks that were found will be listed. You can right-click on any of these and go to Bindings, where you'll have the options of: Before Build, After Build, Clean Build, and Project Open. Simply select the binding type you prefer, and then this task will be automatically run on that event.

If your webpack tasks aren't included, you may need the [Webpack Task Runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner) from Mads Kristensen. It says it supports VS 2015 and 2017, so my assumption is that support is not built-in and you will need to install this. Once you've done so, the procedure outlined above should work without issue.

Comment: Yep that the is extension I have, my question is to build and launch without third party extensions. Like the Vue template from .NET Core v2 did. I believe the angular and react templates also run without third party extensions (I may be wrong)